# Visual studio Show disassembly window and shows a message that says "Source might have changed"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have been trying to figure out what is the cause of this weird problem since morning. I have all my projects in a single solution. and they refer to each other with project reference not a DLL reference. So I expect them to update and notify each other whenever any code change happens.

Now, while dubugging the code,when I try to step-into a method which belongs to a particular project, it shows me diassembly window. I have no idea why am I seeing such a window. I did browse online and some people suggested that I should disable "Enable just my code option" from Debug menu. I did try that as well but no help so far.

I was also seeing another dialog box saying that "Source code might have changed in other assembly" but that is replaced by this disassembly widnow now.

I have no idea why each of them are showing up and also no idea why it switched from the dialog to disassembly window.

Also, If it clean + rebuild the solution, it allows me to step into that project ONCE but after that the same story starts happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens when your `.pdb` files don't match your `.dll` files.

Maybe you have some post-build events changing things, or you have several builds outputting to the same location?

If you are copying another project's assemblies into your project, make sure you keep the `.pdb` files in sync.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I do have post-build events that are copying the DLL and PDB files from one location to other. Deleting that folder once and letting load all the DLLs and PDBs again solved the issue.